# Site for multi countires - multiple websites or multiple stores?

Tags: magento

we have to set up a site for multiple countires with "English" language.

```
1)Countires : India & USA.

2)For indian customers, we need to display "RS" as currency & "$" for US.

3)Shipping charges will be more for US Customers.

4)Products , Product prices & categories are same

5)COD is available in India & not for US customers.

6)In Product view page, we support "check delivery availability" & different zip codes for India & US.

7)we want to use same domain name for both.
```

If we use sub-domain, again we have to upload products for different databases, so we want to ignore it.

now IS it better to use multiple websites or single website with multiple stores ?

I think Store view is not required as we are using only one language as English ?

or one Store view is mandatary per one store ?

please guide me what is best procedure.

Comment: There's loads of existing literature on this. I'd start by Googling  `magento multiple countries`

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for your comment, you are absolutely right. i read lot of posts. as in question i mentioned 7 requirements  i want to know which is best one for our requirements.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't really do that type of question I'm afraid. You'll have to look at the many "best practice" guides and see what works for you and what doesn't. That's how we all do it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @spylh9999ggr - Why do you keep persisting in asking off-topic questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create as websites. In the requirements you mentioned  `1)` and `2)` depends on the way you configure. The other `3), 4), 5), 6) and 7)` depends on how you are configuring each of their properties.

> 1)Countires : India & USA. - Can be configured as different websites
>
> 2)For indian customers, we need to display "RS" as currency & "$" for
>   US - This can be managed from Magento Admin-> System->Manage
>   Currency-> Symbols
>
> 3)Shipping charges will be more for US Customers. - This can be
>   managed from Magento admin->System->Configuration->Sales ->Shipping
>   Methods. I think you will have two different shipping methods for both
>   the countries.
>
> 4)Products , Product prices & categories are same - They will be
>
> 5)COD is available in India & not for US customers. - This can be
>   managed from Magento admin->System->Configuration->Sales ->Payment
>   Methods-> Cash on delivery selecting only india in `Payment from
>   Specific Countries`
>
> 6)In Product view page, we support "check delivery availability" &
>   different zip codes for India & US. - There are couple of extensions
>   out there to help on this or you develop it on your own.
>
> 7)we want to use same domain name for both. - They can be used.

Let me know if you have further queries

Comment: if i want to display multiple currecny symbol for mulitple store ,than is it possible from 2 different stores or we need to create 2 different websites only ?

Comment: Currency symbol can be set for store only, so two different store is sufficient.

Comment: thanks, what about different prices for different countires for same products ? we need websites or stores can handle this ?

Comment: We need different websites to configure different prices. So you may have to create different websites and store within them.

Comment: regarding domain name ? means we want "`www.example.com`" as domain name for both countires, we dont want `www.example.com/ind` and `www.example.com/usa` ? - is both websites and stores will handle this ? –

Comment: totally which is having more advantages- websites or stores?

Comment: I think it will accessible directly from your domain name. That is managed by magento itself

Comment: You need both. Each store has to sit in a website. so you may have to create US store within US website and Indian store within Indian website.

Comment: is we have to create new theme for websites/stores or is we have to copy complete folder of "magento" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110497/discussion-between-sneha-s-and-spylh9999ggr).